# time in C++ calculation

Tags: c++, windows, unix, time

I have a text file with records in it. I need to decide if the time (which is part of the record structure) is between 2 times (stored in strings) that represents the lower and upper range.
In the file the time is represented in 145540123456, which means 14 is the hour, 55 - minutes, 40 - seconds, 123456 - micrseconds accurate.

The upper and lower time that I get to decide if it is in the range, I get it as a string in the same format for instance "093000000000". How do I make the calculation, do I need to do it with time_t and time library?

Note: I can't use Boost.

Comment: convert the number to a `long long` and compare (this will work as long as the range does not span multiple days.)

Comment: You could sort the string values (upper, lower and record-time), since your format makes them sort perfectly alphabetically. If record time is first or last in sequence, it's out of range. One caveat is that the times should all be on the same day.

Comment: Are u sure that I can compare the logic time using the string comparison ? Can't I get order of time that is incorrect ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format you specify has the simple advantage that sorting these time-strings alpha-numerically will keep them in the correct order.

Therefore, using `strcmp` (simple C function if using null-terminated char * buffers), or the comparison operators for `std::string` can allow you to determine easily if a certain time string belongs to an interval.

These methods can lead to very few calculations, if, for example, the first character of the strings you compare differs, since the standard functions should be smart enough to stop comparing the strings as soon as they have determined the result.

Comment: Are u sure that I can compare the logic time using the string comparison ? Can't I get order of time that is incorrect ?

Comment: It will work as long as the hour is always 0 prefixed, which you indicated it was.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not substracting those numbers, you should be able to just compare them as numbers. The one that represents longer time will always be a greater number too. This is because you have the units that weigh most at the left end (hours) and the units that weigh least at the right end (microseconds), which is the same system as the normal numbers use.

Just convert it to unsigned int64 or something, not just int, as that will get overflowed with a number like 145540123456.

Comment: Are u sure that I can compare the logic time using the string comparison ? Can't I get order of time that is incorrect ?

Comment: That would be impossible given the format you've provided. Try to think of an example of two times where this happens and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, just convert it to a number and compare.  Your format puts the most significant digits on the left.  Your highest possible number is `235,959,999,999`, which won't fit in a unsigned long.

A simple way is to split it at the HHMMSS and mmmmmm -- if the first numbers are equal, compare the second.

Answer (score 0):

The best way (c) to handle date/time calculations in C++ is the [Boost.Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/date_time.html) library.

Unfortunately your strings aren't in any standard format. So you would have to parse them yourself and use this as input to a posix time duration.

If you cannot use any library you can simply define a struct with hour, minutes, seconds and microseconds members and `operator<`.
Then simply parse the input into those structs and compare them.

Another options is to convert each duration in microseconds. The comparison becomes trivial then.

Comment: This really depends if he wants to use the times further in his application or if this is just a one time check. At one point he might want to print stuff so he would have to parse it etc.